# Can't upload two or more files using FTPClient node.js module

Tags: node.js, put, ftp-client

I'm using node, and the node-ftp module. I need to upload two files to another server, I'm able to upload one file, but when I try uploading two files it throws back and error.

according to their api, this is the code for sending a file

```
var fs = require('fs');
conn.put(fs.createReadStream('/var/www/videoComplete/'+ videoID +'.flv'), '/home/wowza/content/'+ videoID +'.flv', function(e) {
  console.log(fileName + '.flv uploaded to Streaming Server :)');
  conn.end();
});
```

which works fine, but if i want to do two file I assume I would have to just repeat that function, but it won't work. Does anyone know how to send two or more files using FTPClient

here is the the code I'm trying to execute

```
conn = new FTPClient({ host: 'serverIP' });
conn.on('connect', function() {
  conn.auth('user', 'pass', function(e) {
    if (e) throw e;
    var fs = require('fs');

    conn.put(fs.createReadStream('/var/www/ce-videoComplete/'+ videoID +'.flv'), '/home/wowza/content/'+ videoID +'.flv', function(e) {
      console.log(fileName + '.flv uploaded to Streaming Server :)');
      conn.end();
    });

    conn.put(fs.createReadStream('/var/www/ce-thumbnails/'+ videoID +'.jpg'), '/var/www/html/thumbnails/'+ videoID +'.jpg', function(e) {
      console.log(fileName + '.jpg uploaded to Streaming Server :)');
      conn.end();
    });

  });
});
conn.connect();
```

update: I tried this as well, but it won't connect again.

```
conn.put(fs.createReadStream('/var/www/ce-videoComplete/'+ videoID +'.flv'), '/home/wowza/content/'+ videoID +'.flv', function(e) {
  console.log(fileName + '.flv uploaded to Streaming Server :)');
  conn.end();

  conn.put(fs.createReadStream('/var/www/ce-thumbnails/'+ videoID +'.jpg'), '/var/www/html/thumbnails/'+ videoID +'.jpg', function(e) {
    console.log(fileName + '.jpg uploaded to Streaming Server :)');
    conn.end();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code is uploading the two files concurrently over one connection which isn't something FTP supports.  Try putting the second `conn.put` inside the callback of the first one.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, and that makes sense, so i moved the  }): from the first callback after the second call back, it uploads the first file but doesn't seem to run the next conn.put the second time any ideas? I posted the code i tried above.

Comment: Don't you think it makes sense to know which error is thrown? (Use `if (e) console.error(e);` in your callback.) Also make sure, that connection not closed/errored/ended/etc after first file upload (listen to apropriate events). `put` also returns `false` immediately, if operation not available.

Comment: @ThomasDepole See my posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't end the connection until both files are uploaded in series:

```
conn.put(fs.createReadStream('/var/www/ce-videoComplete/'+ videoID +'.flv'), 
    '/home/wowza/content/'+ videoID +'.flv',
    function(e) {
        console.log(fileName + '.flv uploaded to Streaming Server :)');

        conn.put(fs.createReadStream('/var/www/ce-thumbnails/'+ videoID +'.jpg'),
            '/var/www/html/thumbnails/'+ videoID +'.jpg', 
            function(e) {
                console.log(fileName + '.jpg uploaded to Streaming Server :)');
                // Now that both files are uploaded, end the connection.
                conn.end();
            });  
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: I should have noticed that before commenting :) And one more thing — @Thomas, use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or similar lib.

Comment: Thank you!! both of you! it worked. I wish the author of this module wrote more examples in the documentation, at least this example and using a username and password. But thanks guys!

Comment: @ThomasDepole elmigranto makes a good point about checking the `e` error parameter in the callbacks; logging that likely would have helped you discover what was going on.

Comment: I did that, I took out the throw e, to make the code shorter for this post. But it threw an error, but didn't say anything. It basically just e on this line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [FTPimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftpimp), which unlike any other Node FTP module, FTPimp has a proprietary queue that runs everything asynchronously and sequentially, so you can avoid callback hell and coupling dependencies via the following:

[FTPimp.put](http://ftpimp.net/FTP.html#put)

```
ftp.put(['/var/www/ce-videoComplete/'+ videoID +'.flv', '/home/wowza/content/'+ videoID +'.flv'], function (err, filename) {
    console.log(fileName + 'uploaded to Streaming Server :)');
});
ftp.put(['var/www/ce-thumbnails/'+ videoID +'.jpg', '/var/www/html/thumbnails/'+ videoID +'.jpg'], function(err, filename) {
    console.log(fileName + ' uploaded to Streaming Server :)');
    ftp.quit();
});
```

***and*** since `FTPimp.put()` passes the filename to the callback, your logs are a bit simpler as well :) cheers